# javacc，what does 'jjtThis' mean in .jjt file?

Tags: javacc

and what do these mean? in the .jjt file.I couldn't even make any understand of it...

`
jjtThis.setName();

jjtThis.type;

jjtThis.setLength();

jjtThis.correlationName;

jjtThis.setScale();

jjtThis.setPrecision();

jjtThis.add();

jjtThis.tableName;

jjtThis.name;

jjtThis.position;

jjtThis.length;

...
`

what do these methods and fields of jjtThis come from?why I cann't figure out the meanings of these things?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the current node.  See the documentation https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html for more detail.